# How to sessionize data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement to tag user transactions to a session.

A session is defined in such a way that all actions of a user that happens within 5 minutes after the first action of a session belong to that session. We identify a user by the userID

**Sample Source Data**

```
userID  timestamp
1.0     2018-04-08 09:47:57.849
1.0     2018-04-08 09:48:38.762
1.0     2018-04-08 09:49:31.455
1.0     2018-04-08 09:53:18.131
1.0     2018-04-08 09:55:42.875
1.0     2018-04-08 10:15:04.757
2.0     2018-04-08 10:15:41.368
2.0     2018-04-08 10:19:10.744
2.0     2018-04-08 19:20:37.441
3.0     2018-04-08 19:21:00.315
```

**Expected Output**

```
userID  timestamp                NewSession
1.0     2018-04-08 09:47:57.849  1
1.0     2018-04-08 09:48:38.762  0
1.0     2018-04-08 09:49:31.455  0
1.0     2018-04-08 09:53:18.131  1
1.0     2018-04-08 09:55:42.875  0
1.0     2018-04-08 10:15:04.757  1
2.0     2018-04-08 10:15:41.368  1
2.0     2018-04-08 10:19:10.744  0
2.0     2018-04-08 19:20:55.441  1
3.0     2018-04-08 19:21:00.315  1
```

I am new to python, so need community help.
I wrote below python code but it is checking 5 min gap between two consecutive transaction whereas I need to map all transaction to same session which is within 5 min internal.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r".\Data\Test.csv", names=['userID','timestamp'], 
                 parse_dates=[1])

df.sort_values(by=['userID','timestamp'], inplace=True)

cond1 = df.timestamp-df.timestamp.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta(5, 'm')
cond2 = df.userID != df.userID.shift(1)
df['SessionID'] = (cond1|cond2).cumsum()
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you need help with?

Comment: @jarmod - I have updated question with my code. But the code output is not what I am expecting. Please suggest possible solutions/algorithm. I will try writing that in python

Comment: What is the NewSession in your expected output?

Comment: Why for timestamp `2018-04-08 09:53:18.131` is `NewSession=1` ? The previous timestamp is not 5 minutes ago (`2018-04-08 09:49:31.455`)

Comment: @user2906838 A session is defined in such a way that all actions of a user that happens within 5 minutes after the first action of a session belong to that session. We identify a user by the userID

Comment: @AndrejKesely if you start looking from first data `timestamp =2018-04-08 09:47:57.849`, All transaction in next 5 min session will be same session for that user. In this case 5 min will end at `2018-04-08 09:52:57.849` . Next transaction after this boundary is `timestamp=2018-04-08 09:53:18.131` that is why NewSession=1

Answer (score 0):

We can start to define the session using a `groupby` and a `transform` like so :

```py
>>> df['NewSession'] = (df.groupby('userID')['timestamp']
...                       .transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt('5Min').cumsum()) + 1)
>>> df
    userID  timestamp               NewSession
0   1.0     2018-04-08 09:47:57.849          1
1   1.0     2018-04-08 09:48:38.762          1
2   1.0     2018-04-08 09:49:31.455          1
3   1.0     2018-04-08 09:53:18.131          1
4   1.0     2018-04-08 09:55:42.875          1
5   1.0     2018-04-08 10:15:04.757          2
6   2.0     2018-04-08 10:15:41.368          1
7   2.0     2018-04-08 10:19:10.744          1
8   2.0     2018-04-08 19:20:37.441          2
9   3.0     2018-04-08 19:21:00.315          1
```

Then we can check the new session using `diff` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['NewSession'] = df.groupby('userID')['NewSession'].diff(1).fillna(1)
>>> df
    userID  timestamp               NewSession
0   1.0     2018-04-08 09:47:57.849        1.0
1   1.0     2018-04-08 09:48:38.762        0.0
2   1.0     2018-04-08 09:49:31.455        0.0
3   1.0     2018-04-08 09:53:18.131        0.0
4   1.0     2018-04-08 09:55:42.875        0.0
5   1.0     2018-04-08 10:15:04.757        1.0
6   2.0     2018-04-08 10:15:41.368        1.0
7   2.0     2018-04-08 10:19:10.744        0.0
8   2.0     2018-04-08 19:20:37.441        1.0
9   3.0     2018-04-08 19:21:00.315        1.0
```

Comment: The output is incorrect, `2018-04-08 09:55:42.875` for userID 1 should be grouped with the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using a helper function that groups consecutive timestamps as long as they are within a given threshold (here 5min) of the first value:

```
## pre-requisite, "timestamp" needs to be datetime type
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

def get_groups(s, thresh='5min'):
    out = [1]+[0]*(len(s)-1)
    ref = s.iloc[0]
    for i, val in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if (val-ref) > pd.Timedelta(thresh):
            out[i+1] = 1
            ref = val
    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)

df['NewSession'] = df.groupby('userID')['timestamp'].apply(get_groups)
```

output:

```
   userID               timestamp  NewSession
0     1.0 2018-04-08 09:47:57.849           1
1     1.0 2018-04-08 09:48:38.762           0
2     1.0 2018-04-08 09:49:31.455           0
3     1.0 2018-04-08 09:53:18.131           1
4     1.0 2018-04-08 09:55:42.875           0
5     1.0 2018-04-08 10:15:04.757           1
6     2.0 2018-04-08 10:15:41.368           1
7     2.0 2018-04-08 10:19:10.744           0
8     2.0 2018-04-08 19:20:37.441           1
9     3.0 2018-04-08 19:21:00.315           1
```